# Focus input not working when click outside then use keypress focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, focus

I used angluarJS and Jquery in my website. But i have problem.
When reload page i can use press F4 for focus input and search customer

[image: screenshot]

when i clicked outside then press F4 input text search not working but click on input it's work fine. So how can i fix it ?
Please help me. Thanks.
My HTML

```
<input id="customerSearchInput" placeholder="Tìm kiếm khách hàng (F4)" type="text" class="form-control" focus-me="shouldBeOpen"
    aria-label="Customer" ng-model="searchCustomer" onfocus="this.select();" autocomplete="off"/>
<div class="output-complete output-complete-customer " ng-show="searchCustomer">
    <ul ng-hide="searchCustomer &amp;&amp; list_customer.length == 0">
        <li
            ng-repeat="suggestion in list_customer|filter:searchCustomer|filter:suggestion.customer_code"
            ng-click="customerClicked(suggestion)" index="$index" class="">
            <span class="pull-right">{{suggestion.mobile}}</span>
            <div class="user-info">
                <span class="name-info">{{suggestion.name}}</span>
                <span>Mã: {{suggestion.customer_code}}</span>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="not-found"
        ng-show="searchCustomer &amp;&amp; suggestion.length == 0">Không tìm
        thấy khách hàng phù hợp
    </div>
</div>
```

AngularJS

```
$(()=>{
    $(document).on('keydown', function (event) {
        if (event.which == 115 && event.target.id != 'customerSearchInput') {
            setTimeout(function(){
                $("#customerSearchInput").focus().select();
           },300);
        }

     });
    
})
```